# Elasticsearch: _update_by_query versus terms performance

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, lucene

There is a use case I am working on as described below using elasticsearch:

I have documents(transactions) getting saved in below format:

```
String date
String versionId // UUID
// OTHER FIELDS
```

Each date has multiple version transactions that goes up to few millions in each version(1-100mil)

Problem statement is to fetch only active transactions(with pagination)

- for a given date
- for a specified date range
- for all dates(no date filter)

I have narrowed down my design to below options:

**Option 1:**
Add a new field `active` to maintain the latest version.

```
String date
String versionId
boolean active // Gives me active docs with value set to true
// OTHER FIELDS
```

For every date, I can have multiple versions with only latest versionId transactions set active to `true`. Whenever a new version is being indexed, I am reverting the older versionId transactions active to `false` using `_update_by_query`.

How update happens?

- _update_by_query(wait_for_completion=false) with active = true and set active = false using script.
- Wait for above task to complete.
- Insert new documents(1-100million docs) with next versionId and active = true in *transactions* index.

How search happens? Now, search happens directly on the index(*transactions*) with active = true for all cases:

- for a given date
- for a specified date range
- for all dates(no date filter)

Pagination is through `search_after`.

Questions:

- Is `_update_by_query` efficient here considering the number of docs ranges from 1-100million?

**Option 2:**
Introduce a new index(*transactions_meta*) for meta store with below format:

```
String date
String versionId
boolean active
```

This meta index will have very less data. Each date and versionId will have one document as opposed to many documents in transactions index.

How update happens?

- _update_by_query with active = true and set active = false using script in *transactions_meta* index.
- Insert single document with next versionId and active = true in the *transactions_meta* index.
- Insert new documents(1-100million docs) in same versionId(from above) in *transactions* index.

How search happens?
Now, search is a two step process:

- Search all the documents with active = true in *transactions_meta* index for multiple dates(using `terms` or `range`). Get all documents using `search_after`.
- Then Get unique versionIds from above step.
- Search *transactions* index using `terms` filter having versionIds from above. Pagination is through `search_after`.

Questions:

- Is `terms` filter efficient here? There will be more than 200 terms values.

Which option is better? I am inclined towards option 1.

Comment: In option 2, what `terms` query are you referring to? The one on transactions_meta or the one on transactions?

Comment: `terms` query is on `transactions` index with versionIds from `trasactions_meta`

Comment: A terms query with 200 term values should be ok, but as always you should try it out in your specific context and benchmark